# Set formcollection parameter in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, formcollection

I have an asp.net mvc 4 application. There is an action method, HttpPost which takes in a formcollection. I want to provide a direct link to this action and manually set a parameter on the formcollection. Is this possible?

e.g. myurl?formCollection[Parameter]=staticValue

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide a direct link:

```
<a href="...">Direct link</a>
```

because links use GET's (not POST's). Though you can get the behavior that you want using some javascript or changing the action to HttpGet.

Regards.